# Default value for Django choices field

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose `class Photo` is to hold photos having choice fields and other attributes:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    ONLYME = 'O'
    FRIENDS = 'F'
    PUBLIC = 'P'
    CHOICES = (
        (ONLYME, "Me"),
        (FRIENDS, "Friends"),
        (PUBLIC, "Public"),
    )

    display = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True)
```

Now, how do I set the default or initial value of a photo to `"Friends"` in the `display` attribute?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the [`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default) attribute:

```
display = models.CharField(..., default=FRIENDS)
```

or

```
display = models.CharField(..., default=CHOICES[1][1])
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just set the default attribute:

```
display = models.CharField(default='F', max_length=1, choices=CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
```

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#default).

Answer (score 0):

There is a ChoiceField attribute for RadioButtons, then the solution could be with "initial" attribute... Example:

```
from django import forms
        CHOICES = [("1", "First choice"), ("2", "Second choice")]
    
    class ContactForm(forms.Form):
        choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES, initial="1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is an old question. As of Django 3.0 the canonical way is to use the [`models.TextChoices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) class.

The following is an example that uses the [`Enum` functional api](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#functional-api):

```py
CHOICES = models.TextChoices(
    "Display", (
        ("O", "Me"),
        ("F", "Friends"),
        ("P", "Public"),
    )
)
```

You can then write

```
display = models.CharField(
    max_length=1, choices=CHOICES, default=CHOICES.F, blank=True, null=True
)
```