# Select default value of <select> element in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, html-select

I have a drop down menu that is created in the following fashion:

```
<select id="ip_addr">
    {% for host in hosts %}
        <option value="{{ host.ipaddress }}">{{ host.ipaddress }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

and I don't know how to set the default value.  Normally I would just say something like

```
<option value="0.0.0.0" selected>0.0.0.0</option>
```

but since I am populating this drop down menu with a loop I don't know how to make sure that the option I want is selected.  I'm sure there is a really straight forward way to do this, but I am still pretty new to HTML/JavaScript/Django.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257622/default-value-for-django-choice-field
Here is answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have 2 options, using Django templates built-in features:

1. If you want to set the first host as the default select option
2. If you want to set an specific host as the default select option

Here are the 2 possible solutions:

```
<select id="ip_addr">
    {% for host in hosts %}
        <option value="{{ host.ipaddress }}" {% if forloop.first %}selected{% endif %}>{{ host.ipaddress }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<select id="ip_addr">
    {% for host in hosts %}
        <option value="{{ host.ipaddress }}" {% if host.ipaddress == '0.0.0.0' %}selected{% endif %}>{{ host.ipaddress }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Note: foorloop.first is a special template loop variable, that is True during the first iteration of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to decide the selected index of select.

```js
var obj = document.getElementById("sel");
for(i=0; i<obj.options.length; i++){
    if(obj.options[i].value == "b"){
        obj.selectedIndex = i;
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="sel">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it out after several tests hope it will help:

```
<select>
 {% for priority in priorities %}
  {% if actual_priority == priority %}
   <option select>{{priority}}</option>
  {% else %}
   <option>{{priority}}</option>
  {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
</select>
```

It will be necessary to send "actual_priority" and "priorities" from your view

Answer (score 0):

none of the method mentioned worked for me. But as a work around, I had put the default option as a first element, outside for loop

```
<select name="Customer" id="Customer">
<option value="{{ defaultValue }}" selected >
{{ defaultValue }}
</option>
{% for val in customerlist %}
<option value="{{val}}">{{val}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```