# Setting Django admin default action

Tags: django

I would like to change the default selected action named "---------" (`BLANK_CHOICE_DASH`) to another specific action. Is there a better way to implement this than adding some javascript code that would override the action in load time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [default value for django choice field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257622/default-value-for-django-choice-field)

Comment: @solarissmoke: that's not the same. I want it in the *admin actions*.

Comment: the same concept should apply - you just need to override the corresponding admin forms?

Answer (score 2):

1.Override the `get_action_choices()` method in your `ModelAdmin`, clear the default blank choice and reorder the list。

```
class YourModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def get_action_choices(self, request):
    choices = super(YourModelAdmin, self).get_action_choices(request)
    # choices is a list, just change it.
    # the first is the BLANK_CHOICE_DASH
    choices.pop(0)
    # do something to change the list order
    # the first one in list will be default option
    choices.reverse()
    return choices
```

2.Specific action.Override `ModelAdmin.changelist_view`, use `extra_context` to update `action_form`

`ChoiceField.initial` used to set the default selected choice.
so if your action name is "print_it", you can do this.

```
class YourModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def changelist_view(self,request, **kwargs):
        choices = self.get_action_choices(request)
        choices.pop(0)  # clear default_choices
        action_form = self.action_form(auto_id=None)
        action_form.fields['action'].choices = choices
        action_form.fields['action'].initial = 'print_it'
        extra_context = {'action_form': action_form}
        return super(DocumentAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)
```

Comment: <pre>choices = super(DocumentAdmin, self).get_action_choices(request)</pre>

should be

<pre>choices = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_action_choices(request)</pre>

Comment: @NilsZenker ok. fix it

Answer (score 1):

in your admin.py file

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_action_choices(self, request, **kwargs):
        choices = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_action_choices(request)
        # choices is a list, just change it.
        # the first is the BLANK_CHOICE_DASH
        choices.pop(0)
        # do something to change the list order
        # the first one in list will be default option
        choices.reverse()
        return choices
```

and in your class

```
class TestCaseAdmin(MyModelAdmin):
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can override the `get_action_choices()` method in the `ModelAdmin`.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_action_choices(self, request, default_choices=BLANK_CHOICE_DASH):
        """
        Return a list of choices for use in a form object.  Each choice is a
        tuple (name, description).
        """
        choices = [] + default_choices
        for func, name, description in six.itervalues(self.get_actions(request)):
            choice = (name, description % model_format_dict(self.opts))
            choices.append(choice)
        return choices
```