# How to remove "---------" in django admin action

Tags: django, django-admin

I have no idea how to remove "--------" default action value in django admin.

or replace "------" with any other string ("Select Option").

[image]

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try overriding the [`ModelAdmin.get_action_choices`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L796) method. However, this is an undocumented, internal method, so I wouldn't recommend changing it unless it's absolutely essential that you remove/replace the dashes.

Comment: I want to replace dashes with other string.

Comment: The method Alasdair linked to has an option for `default_choices` so just override it with a call to super with a different choice for that.

Answer (score 2):

remove default action

```
class YourModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def get_action_choices(self, request):
    choices = super(DocumentAdmin, self).get_action_choices(request)
    # choices is a list, just change it.
    # the first is the BLANK_CHOICE_DASH
    choices.pop(0)
    return choices
```

replace with other string

```
class YourModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def get_action_choices(self, request):
    default_choices = [("", "-----other string----")]
    return super(DocumentAdmin, self).get_action_choices(request, default_choices)
```

set default action for your action, you can see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41276533/1265727

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Alasdair my issue is resolved.

I use this code in model.py and its change my default option value to `"Select Options"`

```
from django.db.models.fields import BLANK_CHOICE_DASH

    BLANK_CHOICE_DASH = [("", "---------")]
    def get_action_choices(self, request, default_choices=BLANK_CHOICE_DASH):
        """
        Return a list of choices for use in a form object.  Each choice is a
        tuple (name, description).
        """
        choices = [] + default_choices
        for func, name, description in six.itervalues(self.get_actions(request)):
            choice = (name, description % model_format_dict(self.opts))
            choices.append(choice)
        return choices
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to import `BLANK_CHOICE_DASH` or duplicate the code from the method. Just define `MY_BLANK_CHOICE_DASH = [("", "My text")]`, then do `return super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_action_choices(request, default_choices=MY_BLANK_CHOICE_DASH)`.

Answer (score 0):

After some time later, i also find a solution of this problem..

***You can also override empty_value_display for all admin pages with AdminSite.empty_value_display, or for specific fields like this:***

```
from django.contrib import admin

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name', 'title', 'view_birth_date')

    def view_birth_date(self, obj):
        return obj.birth_date

    view_birth_date.short_name = 'birth_date'
    view_birth_date.empty_value_display = '???'
```